# Insert/Update row in multiple databases

Tags: php, database, sql-server-2008, synchronization

I have a project that involves Software as a Service. The app has one SystemDB  and multiple customer databases. The customer databases are exactly the same(all tables are equal).
The system databases contains a table with all the details from the customer databases like dbname, dbPassword,dbUsername, etc..

How can i do an update to all databases and make sure that the update is correct.
For example. all db's have a translation table. I want to add a word to all tables.
Or i want to update a word that has been misspelled. 
I have more than 50 db's  that we are going to maintain. so manual work is not possible.

Any suggestions on software or frameworks that can do this.

I am Using PHP5.4.0 but no specific framework yet.as DB we use MS Sql 2008R2

Thanks,

Comment: im the same situation i have one table that lists all dbs. then I just loop through then all with the changes

Comment: Would it be worth considering to have this translate table in it's own database and let all the projects access that value from that database?

Comment: @RobinCastlin I cannot do this. its not only the translation table. their are many more table i have to keep in sink + if i send everyone to one db. I think we are going to have issues on load balancing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have simillar situation to read from multiple database,our pl is C#.net.
For that we have written a C#.net code which runs and connect to each database one by one and manages the data into a single server.
I suggest you to go that way only and whatever scripts like update or insert sripts should be used as Excecute Query in .Net.
In this we you will avoid manual work of connecting and updating.

Comment: This sounds intresting, but how do you manage consistancy? I mean what if in the middle of an update your server stops? Then their is a part up to date, but the rest stays unaffected? How do you handle this then?

Comment: When we load data from any server we first load it completely into a CSV file and then read the file to load in the database. In this way the CSV file act as middle layer and if there is any error in server stop like this ...the CSV file will not generate.

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this using replication, which is implicitly supported by SQL Server. Replication allows you to publish certain tables in your system database (the publisher), and subscribe to data changes from one or more customer databases (the subscribers). Since you are only pushing data in one direction, and are mirroring certain tables and the system database, this will work well for you.

You can set up replication from SSMS. Expand the Replication branch under the server in the object explorer, right click "Local publications" and select Create Publication. The wizard will guide you through the publishing process. Do the same for subscriptions, and create a subscription for each of your customer databases.

Since you have a lot of customer databases, it will be worth your while creating the subscription using t-sql, and then duplicating that code across all of your target databases. Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms147346.aspx for instructions on how to do this.

Comment: Thanks for the comment i am going to check this one out. can be a solution i think.

Answer (score 0):

use database triggers to update the tables in other databases.

Answer (score 0):

i am afraid there is no magic wand for this to be done. but if you do feel like doing some magic try using ORM. it makes life so easier.

my favorite is

Doctrine ORM - http://www.doctrine-project.org/

ofcourse there are many others too like. [Propel](http://www.propelorm.org/), [RedbeanPHP](http://redbeanphp.com/).

Comment: I wish it was this simple :(. The problem is that the aplication is more or less running and written already. In the past it was only for one company, but they want to expand it over all their offices :(